# Why does the \linespread in the preamble cause modifications on the leadings without utilizing the \selectfont?

Tags: fonts, spacing, baseline

My question is clear by the title. According to the "LATEX2e font selection" manual guide, the `\selectfont` should be followed by the command of `\linespread`. Does anything related carry on inside of `\begin{document}` through which one may exploit the results of the command without invoking `\selectfont`? Please elaborate on the matter.

Comment: All document classes that I'm familiar with specify a default font, and that is the font acted on by a `\linespread` specified in the preamble.

Comment: you have that backwards: `\linespread` must be followed by `\selectfont`

Comment: @barbarabeeton Do you think it is related to the class files? which make us able to use `\linespread` in the preamble without `\selectfont` ?

Comment: LaTeX does `\normalfont` at begin document and this includes `\selectfont`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle There is no error when you use `\linespread` without `\selectfont` (just in the preamble) and it's working properly. My question is why?

Comment: @egreg Can you tell me the line number according to the `latex.ltx` file, where I can found those codes?

Comment: yes but you misquoted fntguide  in your question above.  It does _not_ say that `\selectfont` should be followed by `\linespread` it says the reverse.  `\linespread` has effect at the next `\selectfont` so if you do it in the preamble it takes effect at the `\normalfont` in `\begin{document}`

Answer (score 1):

If `\linespread` is issued in the preamble, its effect will be on the whole document, because LaTeX will perform `\normalfont` as part of `\begin{document}` and `\normalfont` ends with `\selectfont`.

Generally, every font selection command, including commands that set the baseline skip, take effect after the next `\selectfont` command, which is implicit in `\normalfont`, `\itshape`, `\large` and other font declarations.

*Every* document class has the duty of performing `\normalfont` at begin document, as specified in the manuals.